# How to transform Array.forEach to asynchronous with Q.js?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, breeze, q

I need to execute dynamically a function for all items of an array, but `Array.forEach` execute in sequence and I need execute in asynchronous.

```
items.forEach(function(item) {
    doSomething(item);
});
```

I try this:

```
var promises = [];

items.forEach(function(item) {
    var promise = function() {
        return Q.fcall(function() {
            doSomething(item);
        });
    };
    promises.push(promise());
});

Q.all(promises).then(function () {
    otherFunction(datacontext.mainList); //use datacontext.mainList filled.
});
```

But the execution is always in sequence and I need the execution in parallel.

The `doSomething(item)` method:

```
function doSomething(item) {
        var children = getChildren(item); //get data from local with manager.executeQueryLocally
        var total = getTotal(children); //simple calculations
        datacontext.mainList.push({
            name: item.firstName() + ' ' + item.lastName(),
            total: total
        });
    }
```

Please help me.

Comment: Look up WebWorkers, javascript is single-threaded.

Comment: you can put items.forEach in setTimeout. setTimeout(function () {(your code goes here)}, 1)

Comment: You're trying to use the wrong tool for the job.  Promises are not a tool to convert synchronous code into asynchronous code.  They are a means of taming the complexity of asynchronous callback chains.

Comment: This isnt code review but this is a good place for map `var promises = items.map(function() {/*create promise*/ return promise;});`

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by “asynchronous”? “asynchronous” implies that `doSomething` will not be finished in one event. If it *does* finish in one event, it will always be executed in “serial”, but not necessarily in order. If `doSomething` returns a promise, or has a callback, and won’t finish in a single event, that opens up the possibility of “parallel”, where multiple jobs will have events that are interleaved. Either way, I can provide tips.

Comment: The method `doSomething` is very lazy and I need to execute the method in "parallel". How to execute this method in parallel?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This answer assumes that `doSomething` is itself an asynchronous operation. This means that it will have to yield to the event loop and wait for another event at least once in a while. If `doSomething` is synchronous, there is no benefit to composing it asynchronously.

Within the realm of composite asynchronous jobs, there are serial and parallel variations. The serial model causes job(n + 1) to begin only after job(n) finishes. The parallel model starts all jobs initially and finishes when all jobs are finished. In both of these regards, I can give you tips.

In parallel, you can use Array map and Q.all, assuming `doSomething` accepts a value from `jobs` and returns a promise:

```
return Q.all(jobs.map(doSomething))
```

To do jobs in serial order, use Array reduce.

```
return jobs.reduce(function (previous, job) {
    return previous.then(function () {
        return doSomething(job);
    });
}, Q());
```

If you want to perform jobs in serial, but only proceed to the next job depending on the result of the first, you can use `reduceRight` to compose a function.

```
return jobs.reduceRight(function (next, job) {
    return function (previous) {
        return doSomething(job).then(function (result) {
            if (result.isGood(previous)) return result;
            return next(result);
        });
    });
}, function fallthrough(previous) {
    throw new Error("No result was satisfactory");
})();
```

If you have an array that contains *functions* that need to be executed in order, feeding the output of the previous into the input of the next, you can use `reduce` even more succinctly.

```
return functions.reduce(Q.when, Q());
```

The tutorial in Q’s readme covers more cases and I am told has been helpful https://github.com/kriskowal/q#tutorial

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though you are executing the promise you are creating immediately during iteration as you push it to the array. Try changing...

```
promises.push(promise());
```

To...

```
promises.push(promise);
```

Comment: I had tested with `promises.push(promise);` but this didn't work, and this code `promises.push(promise());` didn't execute the promise, the code `Q.all(promises)` execute all promises but in sequence.

Comment: Is your doSomething(item) method a synchronous method? Q will not turn your synch method into an asynch method. Your doSomething  function needs to be asynch.

Comment: Yes, It is. Please help me. How to transform doSomething(item) in asynchronous method?

Comment: I have edited my question and add `doSomething(item)` method.

Comment: You would need to either rewrite your doSomething method to make use of using callbacks. Or... You could use the async (https://github.com/caolan/async#asyncjs) library to convert your sync code to async. 

Which, in addition if there is not a need for promises in your code then you should get rid of Q...

Comment: "But `async.js` is made for asynchronous tasks only". Review this question [How to execute functions in parallel with async.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744724/how-to-execute-functions-in-parallel-with-async-js)

Comment: Check this question: [Parallel.js have problems with Blob in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744104/parallel-js-have-problems-with-blob-in-ie)